# Preservar 'rownames' após uso de funções da família apply

Tags: r, apply

Faço uso das funções `apply` e, preciso que `rownames` fique no banco de dados após execução destas. Considere:

```
dataframe=structure(list(Composição100g = structure(c("Valor energético (KJ)", 
"Proteína", "Glicídios", "Açúcar", "Amido", "Gorduras totais", 
"Gorduras saturadas", "Colesterol", "Fibras", "Sódio", "Ferro", 
"Ácido fólico", "Vitamina D", "Vitamina B12", "Vitamina C"), format.spss = "A22", display_width = 17L), 
    AllBran = structure(c(1150, 13, 46, 17, 29, 4.5, 0.9, 0, 
    28, 0.8, 8.8, 250, 3.1, 1, 0), format.spss = "F8.1"), Crunch = structure(c(1600, 
    6, 83, 39, 44, 2.5, 1, 0, 3, 0.7, 7.9, 333, 0, 0.8, 0), format.spss = "F8.1"), 
    CornFlakes = structure(c(1600, 7, 84, 7, 77, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 
    2.5, 0.9, 7.9, 167, 4.2, 0.8, 0), format.spss = "F8.1"), 
    ChocoKrispis = structure(c(1600, 6, 85, 35, 50, 2, 0.5, 0, 
    2, 0.6, 7.9, 333, 0, 0.8, 0), format.spss = "F8.1"), Muesli = structure(c(1150, 
    10, 58, 15, 43, 10, 2.5, 0, 9, 0.1, 5, 2, 3, 1, 0), format.spss = "F8.1"), 
    SpecialK = structure(c(1600, 16, 75, 17, 58, 1, 0.3, 0, 2.5, 
    0.8, 23.3, 333, 8.3, 1.7, 100), format.spss = "F8.1"), FrootLoop = structure(c(1550, 
    14, 74, 22, 52, 1, 0.3, 0, 3.5, 0.7, 21, 300, 7.5, 1.5, 90
    ), format.spss = "F8.1")), .Names = c("Composição100g", 
"AllBran", "Crunch", "CornFlakes", "ChocoKrispis", "Muesli", 
"SpecialK", "FrootLoop"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Onde executei:

```
#inserir uma variável comum como rownames
row.names(cereais)<-cereais$Composição100g
cereais[1]<-NULL
```

e, após:

```
cereais<-data.frame(cereais<-apply(cereais,2,as.numeric))
```

e `rownames` é resetada. Tentei algumas funções encontradas no **SO**, mas, quando não dá erro, cria-se uma lista (o que não quero).

O que fazer para preservar `rownames` dentro do dataframe após usar funções `apply`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema do seu código, e de perder o atributo `names` é que está a complicar o que é muito mais simples.

Em primeiro ligar, `data.frame()` é uma função e portanto para atribuir um valor a um argumento da função deve usar `=` e não `<-`. Seria assim:

```
data.frame(cereais = apply(cereais,2,as.numeric)))
```

Em segundo lugar, não é necessário atribuir um nome, `cereais` ao resultado de `apply` dentro da função `data.frame()`. Basta coagir o resultado de `apply`, um objeto de classe `matrix`, em um objeto de classe `data.frame`. Isso faz-se com a função `as.data.frame`.

```
cereais2 <- as.data.frame(apply(cereais, 2, as.numeric), row.names = row.names(cereais))
```

Agora já está tudo bem.

No entanto, gostava ainda de dizer que as funções `lapply` e `sapply` são melhores neste caso. Aplicam-se a objetos de classe `list` e como as `data.frame`'s são listas tornam o código ainda mais simples. Não é necessário passar a dimensão, o `sapply` vai processar cada vetor coluna, os membros da lista.

```
cereais3 <- as.data.frame(sapply(cereais, as.numeric), row.names = row.names(cereais))
```

Os resultados são idênticos.

```
identical(cereais2, cereais3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Entendi o conceito que passou, @Rui Barradas. No entanto, meu objetivo é o de manter `rownames`, isto é, a coluna que nomeia as linhas do dataframe. Quando executo a minha (e a sua) função, os seus nomes são substituidos por números (1,2,3...).

Comment: @Giovani Perdão, li mal! Vou ver melhor...

Comment: @Giovani Feito, veja agora.

Comment: Tudo certo, @Rui Barradas. Grato.